# Mount and external hard rive on an Amazon ec2 Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm using the amazon EC2 servers for the first time, so I'm sorry if i'm not understanding something obvious.

I alredy created and connected to an EC2 instance with a ssh connection. I'm trying to use it to run some heavy c++ code but I need to use some data in my external hard drive to do it.

There's anyway that I can connect my usb external disk to my ubuntu server withou copying the files?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't think this is a coding question. Are you asking how to mount a USB drive on an ubuntu server? http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that programming questions in general were ok. Yes that wold be a solution, I dont know how to make the server recognise my USB devices.

Comment: You're better off heading over to askubuntu.com to ask the question.

Comment: I didnt know that an ask ubuntu existes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to attach a local USB drive to an Amazon EC2 instance.  This is not specific to Ubuntu as some comments suggested.
To use data from an application running on Amazon EC2, you must made these data available from the Cloud.  The most efficient way is to store your data on AWS' infrastructure (have a look at Amazon S3 and Elastic Block Store)
To initially import your data, several options are available depending on the size of your data set and the velocity of it.  Internet transfer is the easiest (you can use scp to your instance).  For larger volumes, you can ship your data on an external hard drive using a courier service (Amazon import / export) and large companies can rent a dedicated line between their data centers and AWS facilities (AWS Direct Connect)

Seb

Answer (score 0):

You can connect USB drive to aws instance (Windows) using Digi Anywhere usb. Firstly create vpn connection to the network where anywhereusb is located. After that configure vpn on aws instance. Plug in usb device into anywhereusb and it should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows EC2 instance it is pretty much possible using RDP. For Linux instances I think its not possible because you must have to login using SSH and there is no interactive option where you can attach external drive to Linux instances.